# How to get current language in Play Framework 2.2 (Java)?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I try to print the current language in my .scala.html view

```
@Lang.code()
```

and the result is

```
Compilation error
value code is not a member of object play.i18n.Lang
```

Why is that? API doc 2.2 for play.i18n.Lang says

```
public java.lang.String code() 
The Lang code (such as fr or en-US).
```

How can I get the current language?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Add a Lang implicit parameter to your template (.scala.html file) like this:

`@()(implicit lang: Lang)`

Then you can access the language in the template file like: `@lang.code` - as the [API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.6/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.Lang) says

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed you can do `@Controller.lang().code()`

Comment: This is also possible. You can even change the language with `Controller.changeLang("de");`

Comment: Noticed another problem. Putting `@()(implicit lang: Lang)` in .scala.html page prints `(implicit lang: Lang)` in HTML source.

Comment: You should put this at the top of your template file - along with the other parameters

Comment: It was at the top. No matter what line it is in my template, it will produce output as described above in HTML source. If it is before <!DOCTYPE..> it messes the document.

Comment: Can you post your template file (the relevant parts)